# Not able to open Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.14 beta

Tags: xcode8, macos-mojave

I recently upgraded to new beta version of macOS 10.14 but after installing it when I tried to open my older version of Xcode 8.3.2, every time it gets crashed. Below is its details.

> Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData

[image: Xcode 8.3.2 crash log]

Comment: Did you try deleting all Xcode caches? It might help. See my answer at https://superuser.com/a/1147209/430478 for example.

Comment: did not worked for me. I hate this update!

Comment: This happened to me as well. I had to revert to High Sierra just for Xcode 8 to work on my end

Comment: @jaytrixz how to revert? time machine backup?

Comment: So, if you want XCode 8, did you try to upgrade first to 8.3 ?

Comment: I also couldn't get Xcode 8.3.3 to run on Mojave. I'm trying to bootstrap a legacy application that requires Xcode >8 <8.3.3. RIP

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 8.X.X is doesn't support on macos 10.12 later version.

> **Cause of issue:** "DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing"

and also doesn't meet the swift version. so you need to upgrade your Xcode version or downgrade your os version below 10.12

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in a few places like [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109434) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8566927), Xcode 8 does not run on Mojave.   The best approach at this point is to either migrate your application to run with the latest Xcode, or run a VM with High Sierra or earlier that still supports your required version of Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 8's some versions is not compatible with macOS 10.14 just because of swift version.
So, if you want XCode 8, did you try to upgrade first to 8.3 ?

Comment: citation needed