# macOS 10.14 Mojave can't open Xcode 8.3.3 (immediately crash)

Tags: xcode, macos

I used Xcode 9.0 and Xcode 8.3.3 on my mac (High Sierra) before. Yesterday, I update my mac system to Mojave, and my Xcode 8.3.3 can't open after update system. How to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Solve it by upgrading to Xcode 10 or running Xcode 8.3.3 in a virtual machine.

Comment: I upgrade my Xcode 8 to Xcode 10, but the Xcode 8.3.3 still crash

Comment: @v2Next I think the idea was to use Xcode 10 instead of using the very out-of-date Xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: Because work needs so I must use the Xcode 8.3.3.

Comment: Same issue is occurring with Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Needed to update Swift 2 projects to Swift 3. Xcode 10 won't open or compile Swift 2.

Comment: @rmaddy the main problem with xcode 9+ for me, that you can't time profile your apps on iOs 9 : / And if you want to get your apps run normally on iPhone 4s, for example, it becomes a headache

Comment: Duplicate of [Not able to open Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.14 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725674/not-able-to-open-xcode-8-3-2-on-macos-10-14-beta)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to open Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.14 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725674/not-able-to-open-xcode-8-3-2-on-macos-10-14-beta)

Answer (score 2):

It seems Xcode 8.3.3 doesn't support on macos 10.12 later version.
You'd better run it in a VM with High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

After macOS Mojave upgrade, I encountered this. And unfortunately the only solution that I found is to reload XCode from App Store from scratch to the latest version.

After that everything works perfect.

It seems related with the access grants that Mojave keeps asking of.