# xcode 8 can't be opened on macOS 10.14

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode8

I am trying to migrate Swift 2 to Swift 4 but I need to have xcode 8 to do that. My problem is, the latest update on MacOS Mojave 10.14 does not allow me to open the outdated xcode 8.

Anyone know another to convert swift 2 to swift 3 or 4? Or another way to download xcode 8 instead of updating xcode 8 to 10?

[image: error]

Comment: I just went through what exactly you are going through now a day or two ago.  I had to install Xcode 8 on a 10.12 partition on an external hard drive to get from Swift 2 to Swift 3.  Once you have Swift 3, you can go back to Xcode 10 and finish porting to 4.2.  All you need is an extra disk partition or hard drive to solve this.

Comment: Get your desired version of Xcode by navigating from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/3687801). You should be able to install (in your updated macOS) the lower version of Xcode when it has minimum requirements of macOS version. [And you can have two Xcodes installed at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669367/can-i-have-multiple-xcode-versions-installed).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I tried installing xcode 8 onto an external h drive but I cant open xcode still. I added a picture of the error I received

Comment: @nayem I've installed the xcode 8 from apple dev site. But the macOS is not letting me open it

Comment: @booak55 I am facing similar issue. I have Mojave os and got a code with Swift2.x which supports Xcode8.x. Any idea how to work with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to open Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.14 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725674/not-able-to-open-xcode-8-3-2-on-macos-10-14-beta)