# Xcode 7 on Mojave?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, macos-mojave

I have updated to `10.14`. Then I could not launch Xcode 7.3.1 (believe me I wish this were not necessary). I downloaded and re-installed Xcode 7.3.1, but I still get the same error in the "Report to Apple" dialog:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_IVAR_$_NSTextViewIvars.sharedData
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.7.3.1.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
  in /Applications/Xcode.7.3.1.app/Contents/MacOS/../SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
```

I have tried

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer
```

which doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

Note: after each failed attempt to launch, I have to remove the quarantine xattrs with:

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode.7.3.1.app
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need Xcode 7 instead of a later version?

Comment: @Caleb there could be many reasons: (1) compatibility testing of a framework that you distribute ; (2) support for older Swift versions. Note that Apple Store Connect still accepts app uploads built with Xcode 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to open Xcode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.14 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725674/not-able-to-open-xcode-8-3-2-on-macos-10-14-beta)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: still no solution. I had to grab another computer that's not on mojave /-: